# How can I embed a word, excel file to a ppt file using Apache poi library?

Tags: excel, ms-word, zip, apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to insert pdf, zip, excel, word file into a ppt file with the latest apache poi version i.e. 4.1.2.
how can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.